# Would a open Ball B(0,1) be covered by countable infinite mixture of open & closed cubes with max length<1?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, combinatorics, general-topology

From the Open Set Construction Theorem in $\mathbb{R}^n$, all non-empty open sets could be the union of disjoint countable infinite half-open cubes (its edge could be open or closed).

But would a open Ball $ B(0,1) = \{ x|\left|x\right|<1 \} $ be covered (not consistent) by disjoint countable infinite open/closed cubes ( the cover could be the mix of open and closed cubes) with their max length$<1$?

I thought the key whould be on the adjacent edges of the disjoint closed cubes as outside of a closed cube should be four open cubes?
But I don't exactly know how to tell the contradiction.

Comment: maybe we could choose a vertex $x_0$ of a closed cube in the unit ball, and consider the constitution of $ B(x_0,\delta)$ (on the edge of closed cube could only be open cube, what about the angles?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We assume there is a cover of $B(0,1)$ by mixed cubes.

First, find an arbitrary cube $A$ and a peak x $\in$ $B(0,1)$.

Second, in x's neighborhood $B(x,\delta)$ , consider the number of cubes in $B(x,\delta)$ as $\delta$ become sufficiently small. It means how to make up of the $2\pi$ ankle at x. However, the ankle provided by a cube can be $2\pi$ (in the cube), $\pi$(at the edge except for peaks),$\frac{\pi}{2}$(at the peaks).

We've known $A$ provides $\frac{\pi}{2}$ for $x$. Then $2\pi-\frac{\pi}{2}=\frac{3\pi}{2}$ , the probable circumstances are listed:

1. 3 cubes $A_1,A_2,A_3$ . $x$ is a peak of 2 cubes and is on the edge of 1 cube.
2. 4 cubes $A_1,A_2,A_3,A_4$. $x$ is a peak of 4 cubes.

Consider the open-or-closed situation of those circumstances, we try to lead it to a contradiction.

First, if $\forall A, B$ is both closed(open), then $d(A,B):=\sup\{(x,y)|\ x\in A,\ y\in B\}>0$. Secondly, as $x$ is the peak of 2(4) cubes, $\exists$ $A_1,A_2,A_3$( we may assume) , such that $ d(A_1,A_2)=d(A_2,A_3)=d(A_1,A_3)=0$.

We may assume $A_1$ is open, then $A_2$ is closed ($d(A,B)=0)$. Then whether $A_3$ is closed or open would lead to contradiction.

So $B(0,1)$ wouldn't be covered by disjoint countable infinite open/closed cubes.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, your question is as follows:
*Is it possible to cover the unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$ using countably many disjoint open cubes of length strictly less than 1?*

The answer is no. Say we had a covering as you describe. Then the first cube that intersects the unit ball must have a limit point that is in its compliment but inside the unit ball. No other open cube could possibly contain this point, as then the two cubes would not be disjoint. You run into a similar problem if you try to do it with just closed sets.

Of course, if you have complete freedom to decide, for each cube, if each point on the boundary of the cube is included or not, then you won't have any issues. But if you have more strict conditions (i.e., a the whole face of a cube, including its boundary points, and the boundary points of its boundary points, etc), it becomes less clear.

Comment: but the cover could be the mix of open and closed cubes

Comment: I edited this to try to reflect that possibility. It isn't entirely clear to me the exact conditions you are putting on the cubes.